# Save Custom name for picture via camera intent in DCIM/pictures

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gallery, android-file, android-camera-intent

I have followed and literally picked up code from other answers but its still not working.

When a picture is clicked, it's saved by default in DCIM/camera with name such as `20150910_111841.jpg` (`date_timeInMilliseconds`) but I want to save it as "myName_date.jpg".

```
public void OnClick(){
 if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    f = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
                    mMediaUri=Uri.fromFile(new File(f, "MEDIT"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"jpg"));
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mMediaUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        switch(requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mMediaUri.getPath());
                //imgVIew.setImageBitmap(bm);

                Bitmap scaledBitmap=ScaleImage(bm);
                final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, bos);
                //Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));
                imgVIew.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
                imageView.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(scaledBitmap));
                imageView1.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bm));
                    break;
            case REQUEST_GALLERY:

                    //Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    //imageview.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                    break;
        }//Close switch statement

    }else {
        Log.d("Error ", "user canceled !");
    }

}
```

I have not yet added code for the gallery part but that shouldn't be a problem. As of now no matter what I do its being saved as default but I realized if people don't have an SD card then it can cause an issue. I'd rather have this picture available, in the default DCIM location but with a custom name. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code to save the image with the name you want:

```
/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
        /*
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        */
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "the_name_of_directory");

        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("canberra trailpass", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "myName"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

Comment: This is not working for me... Am i missing some manifest permissions? I have placed the write external storage one.

I am placing a Log.d to output the Uri.fromfile(mediaFile).toString and it comes as file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/myName20150910_111841.jpg BUT its still being stored as 20150910_111841.jpg. Basically my problem is I have to capture the image using camera but pass the URi of the image via an intent to another activity and load it there using cursor. If im unable to set the uri then the activity is passing an incorrect uri to the next one.

Comment: Then just try myname.jpg and let me know what are u getting

Comment: getting the same result. Just to confirm a new folder will be made in DCIM correct? Its ok if i use the usual camera folder as well but im not sure if its consistent throughout all phones

Comment: just remove milliseconds and try to save as myname.jpg...then what is the result??

Comment: file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/myName.jpg in the Log.d output but its being saved in default pictures with default name as a time stamp.

Comment: Then try  String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
    myDir.mkdirs();

Comment: Also take write external storage permission

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89234/discussion-between-varun-agarwal-and-kgandroid).

Comment: Hi, could I ask a followup question. This code you have given above works on and off. I noticed just last week that a directory called "the_name_of_directory" exists. So i tried changing JUST that to "medit_prescription" but then it stopped working. Android still ignores the custom URI being generated and stores it in DCIM directory. Could you please help me? This is driving me insane.

Comment: try changing it programatically...in my example relace  the_name_of_directory to that of yours

Comment: I did try to do it just now. The first 3 images got saved, after that they all got saved to the normal DCIM directory. I dont understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It will like, this

```
File fPath = getAlbumStorageDir("myName_date");
File f = new File(fPath, "myName_date" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
```

It's not a device problem,
as example my working code, i have achieve like this,

```
public static Uri getUri(String filePath) {
    File media = new File(filePath);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);
    return uri;
}

public static File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
    if (file.exists()) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "storeage file exists");
    }
    if (!(file.mkdirs() || file.isDirectory())) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "Directory not created");
    }
    return file;
}

public static class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, String> {

    private SaveImageListener listener;

    public SaveImageTask(SaveImageListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        Bitmap bitmapToSave = params[0];

        File fPath = getAlbumStorageDir("AppName");
        File f = new File(fPath, "AppName" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
        String filePath = null;
        try {
            FileOutputStream strm = new FileOutputStream(f);
            bitmapToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, strm);
            strm.close();
            filePath = f.getPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return filePath;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String filePath) {
        super.onPostExecute(filePath);
        listener.onImageSaved(filePath);
    }

    interface SaveImageListener {
        void onImageSaved(String filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean something like this?
                    fPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
                    
File f = new File(fPath, "myName_date" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
                   
 mMediaUri=Uri.fromFile(f);
                    
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mMediaUri);

Comment: This is still not working.. Im getting the picture in DCIM with the default name. Could it be an issue with my phone itself? I guess I can manage without the custom name... as long as its saved in default path.

Answer (score 0):

To use a custom name, replace this -

```
 mMediaUri=Uri.fromFile(new File(f, "MEDIT"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"jpg"));
```

With this -

```
mMediaUri=Uri.fromFile(new File(f, "MEDIT"+"Your Custom Name"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"jpg"));
```

Comment: This makes no difference. MEDIT is my custom name. Concatenating one more string to it doesnt change whatever error I am already making.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri mImageCaptureUri;

Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "example.jpg"));

    takePictureIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            mImageCaptureUri);

    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
```

onActivityResult :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);      

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            switch (requestCode) {

                case 1:

                    if(mImageCaptureUri!=null) {

                    imageName = "";
                    Bitmap bitmap = getCameraImage(activity, mImageCaptureUri);

                    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap );

                    removeFile(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());

                    break;
            }
    }
}
```

get camera image :

```
public static Bitmap getCameraImage(Activity activity, Uri mImageCaptureUri){

if(mImageCaptureUri==null) {

        return null;

    } else {

        activity.getContentResolver().notifyChange(mImageCaptureUri, null);
        ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        try {

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 6;

            AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor =null;
            fileDescriptor =
                    cr.openAssetFileDescriptor( mImageCaptureUri, "r");

            bitmap
              = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(
                fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);


            //bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, mImageCaptureUri);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;

    }
}
```